# Guitar options for beginners to learn

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, self-learning, beginner, headphones

I would like to learn to play guitar and I am reviewing the choice of being an autodidact but I want to know the path of the very beginner, to know the type of guitar I should get to start learning, the brand, the price, the materials, etc... to prepare myself to do the investment of money and time, so, what guitar should I get?

Also, I can learn in places where I will not bother anybody, but I want to learn in the commodity of my own room to avoid bother roommates and neighbors, does it exist the possibility to use a guitar with headphones? I know that some electric guitars do not make sound without an amplifier, so can I use some device to instead using only an amplifier, use headphones?

Comment: Hi there - this question gets asked a lot here, so I have closed as duplicate of our canonical-ish one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best guitar to get is the one that will inspire you to pick it up and play. So it really depends upon the type of music that you want to play. You should think of your favorite band or your favorite couple of songs and get the guitar which gets you closest to that kind of sound.

For example, if you want to learn 60s-70s folk songs like (early) Bob Dylan, CSNY, Joan Baez, then get an acoustic guitar.

If you want to learn heavier stuff like Rock or Metal, then get an electric. Broadly speaking, there are 2 basic kinds of electric guitar: ones with single-coil pickups (Fender-y guitars) and ones with humbuckers (Gibson-y guitars) so you should choose the type that the artists you aspire to emulate play. An electric will require an amplifier, but any amp made in the last 20 years will have a headphone jack so you can play without disturbing those around you.

Once you decide roughly what you're looking for (acoustic/electric single-coils/humbuckers) then it's time to go into a music store and actually try a few. Even though you don't know how to play very much or at all, the way the guitar feels in your hands is the most important thing.

If the guitar feels good in your hands and can make the sounds that you want to hear, that will make all the difference when you come home and sit down and have to choose between playing guitar or watching tv or games or whatever else you might do.

Comment: It's a nice idea, but for a raw beginner, there are so many different sorts of guitars available, with a vast array of prices. In my studio are just about every style of guitar available, so students can use them during lessons. That way, they get to know and understand the differences, and are far better informed for later. Self-learning, as the OP is, makes life difficult.